# azureml-sdk: Mount dataset

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to mount a datastore via the sdk, something like this

```
import tempfile
import os
mounted_path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
mount_context = my_datastore.mount(mounted_path)
mount_context.start()
pathes = os.listdir(mounted_path)
n_pathes = len(pathes)

print(n_pathes)
```

Code is working fine on a Compute Instance. However, I'd like to do the same on my local machine. Since it's a Windows machine, I tried to run it in an AzureML Docker Container via VSCode. It seems that the mounting implementation requires libssl1.0.0 to run. Okay, this is not available in Ubuntu >= 18.04. Well, I took another dockerfile with Ubuntu 16.04 but that didn't help. I tried it on a local Linux installation but same problems.

Anyone found a solution to mount AzureML-Datasets on local machines?
Is this libssl1.0.0 requirement somewhere hard-coded in the code?
Bad thing that the source code is not available on GitHub so otherwise I would have opened an issue.
Anyhow, anyone has a solution for this?

Best
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

can you share the error message?
Dataset mount has dependency on fuse driver. you can install it via  `apt-get install -y fuse`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-with-datasets#mount-files-to-remote-compute-targets